# how to fetch json value and equate it with string value in ADF

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

im having variable which has json value

```
{
"name": "new2",
"value": "True"
```

}

i want to take this value and equate with "True", if they are equal then set boolean variable as true or else set it as false in "set variable" activity in ADF.

for above example : boolean variable must be set as true

how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you getting the JSON value from databricks notebook?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work: what you've tried, where you're stuck, output issues, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- If you simply want to equate your variable with Json value to `True`(instead of using above procedure), you have to do it using `contains()`. This is because variables can't be of Object type, so you have to go ahead and use the string of Json value (only if it is of **String** type).

[image]

- In `set variable` activity to get the Boolean result, use the following expression:

```
@contains(variables('output'),'"value": "True"')
```

- Output:

[image]

***You can also use the following alternative procedure which directly uses the output of notebook, as a Json, equates it and gives the required output.***

- Considering you are getting your output from Databricks notebook, Let's say you have an `my_json` variable in your Databricks notebook which has the JSON value.

```
my_json = {"name": "new2","Value": "True"}
```

- Convert this to string and use it to pass the exit value from the databricks notebook in the following manner.

```
output = str(my_json)
dbutils.notebook.exit('{"Json":'+output+'}')
```

[image]

- Now this returns your Json value to data factory notebook activity. Use this value with `set variable` activity to assign `True` to a boolean variable is the **value** (key name) has the value **True** else assign `False`.
- To do this, use `equals()` function where you compare the value of **value** key in json to the string `'True'`. The output of this expression returns a boolean which can be assigned to the `flag` boolean variable.

```
@equals(activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput.Json.value, 'True')
```

- My pipeline:
  [image]
- Output:

[image]

Comment: You're answering a question that has no specific attempt. Please don't do this. Just ask the OP to edit their question to show their work. Otherwise, you're spending your time authoring solutions for people.